# What's the difference between findAndModify and update in MongoDB?

Tags: database, mongodb, sql-update

I'm a little bit confused by the `findAndModify` method in MongoDB. What's the advantage of it over the `update` method? For me, it seems that it just returns the item first and then updates it. But why do I need to return the item first? I read the ***MongoDB: the definitive guide*** and it says that it is handy for manipulating queues and performing other operations that need get-and-set style atomicity. But I didn't understand how it achieves this. Can somebody explain this to me?

Answer (score 179, accepted):

If you fetch an item and then update it, there may be an update by another thread between those two steps.   If you update an item first and then fetch it, there may be another update in-between and you will get back a different item than what you updated.

Doing it "atomically" means you are guaranteed that you are getting back the exact same item you are updating - i.e. no other operation can happen in between.

Comment: I'm still a little bit confused. How does `findAndModify` guarantee that there is no other update operation interfering with it?

Comment: @chaonextdoor findAndModify acquires a lock to the database when it starts the operation so that no other operation can process when it is running. When it finishes the operation it releases the lock.

Comment: findAndModify doesn't actually obtain a lock until the modify part of request. So it is possible for multiple processes to be able to update the same record.

Comment: @MarkUnsworth incorrect. See https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/commands/find_and_modify.cpp#L122 the writeLock is acquired for duration of operation.

Comment: We've seen issues at high load when using findAndModify to manage a job queue. The find looked for jobs with an active status of false and the modify command set the active status to true to prevent other processes from accessing the job, but several processes were actually able to process the same job at the same time.

The processes were all running on separate machines so not a local threading issue

Comment: @MarkUnsworth open a support case with 10gen - if there is a bug in locking with findAndModify I can guarantee you engineers would want to fix it asap.  If that was the case though we would see a lot of people report this behavior but findAndModify works as designed for pretty much everyone who is using it - cases where it seemed like it wasn't came down to logic or implementation bugs on the client side, but of course in complex software there can always be a bug.

Comment: Not sure if there was a ticket ever filed because https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/commands/find_and_modify.cpp#L137 still reads `Lock::DBWrite` - it obtains only a write lock.

Comment: Does findAndModify work for only 1 document? I want to findOneAndModify

Comment: findAndModify by definition only works on a single document, but unless you need the modified document returned, you should simply use "update".

Comment: does anyone know how much faster is Update compared to findAndModify?

Comment: that's not really a meaningful question - it depends on many things - in some cases it is not any faster, in other cases it may be orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky  it sounds like it could still have been given a meaningful answer by you though. If there are examples of cases where it is not faster and examples of where it is, it would probably allow him to infer the specific answer within his own ambiguous context but also lead to a better understanding of the workings of both operations.

Comment: @funkyeah that's a separate question from this one, in any case, so probably belongs in a new question of its own.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky I was considering arguing with you but then realized you are correct so now I'm thinking I should apologize. Sorry!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. I think the other answers are much more useful (i.e. they explain the difference between findAndModify and update instead of simply explaining atomicity)

Comment: the question already specifies that OP understands that findAndModify returns the document being updated, but update does not.  They are asking how that is achieved (plus why such two mechanisms were provided).

Answer (score 60):

`findAndModify` returns the document, update does not.

If I understood Dwight Merriman (one of the original authors of mongoDB) correctly, using update to modify a single document i.e.("multi":false} is also atomic.  Currently, it should also be faster than doing the equivalent update using `findAndModify`.

Answer (score 36):

From the [MongoDB docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#comparisons-with-the-update-method) (emphasis added):

> - By default, both operations modify a single document. However, the update() method with its multi option **can modify more than one document**.
> - If multiple documents match the update criteria, for findAndModify(), you **can specify a sort** to provide some measure of control on which document to update.
>     With the default behavior of the update() method, you cannot specify which single document to update when multiple documents match.
> - By default, findAndModify() method **returns the** pre-modified version of the **document**. To obtain the updated document, use the new option.
>     The update() method returns a WriteResult object that contains the status of the operation. To return the updated document, use the find() method. However, other updates may have modified the document between your update and the document retrieval. Also, if the update modified only a single document but multiple documents matched, you will need to use additional logic to identify the updated document.
> - Before MongoDB 3.2 you cannot specify a write concern to findAndModify() to override the default write concern whereas you **can specify a write concern** to the update() method since MongoDB 2.6.
>
> When modifying a single document, both findAndModify() and the update() method atomically update the document.

Comment: You could always specify write concern to update operation.  In addition, since 3.2 (3.1.1 technically) you can specify write concern to findAndModify as well. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6558

Comment: I have found that in MongDB 3.6, although the doc states `findAndModify()` by default modifies only one doc and `update()` can updates one or more doc, when I use an `arrayFilters`, `findAndModify()` updates all matches. Maybe it is a bug??

Comment: There is no bug - arrayFilters allow you to update multiple array elements but they are still in a single document.

Answer (score 10):

One useful class of use cases is counters and similar cases. For example, take a look at this code (one of the MongoDB tests):
[find_and_modify4.js](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/jstests/core/find_and_modify4.js).

Thus, with `findAndModify` you increment the counter and get its incremented
value in one step. Compare: if you (A) perform this operation in two steps and
somebody else (B) does the same operation between your steps then A and B may
get the same last counter value instead of two different (just one example of possible issues).

Answer (score 9):

This is an old question but an important one and the other answers just led me to more questions until I realized: **The two methods are quite similar and in many cases you could use either.**

- Both `findAndModify` and `update` perform atomic changes within a single request, such as incrementing a counter; in fact the `<query>` and `<update>` parameters are largely identical
- With both, the atomic change takes place directly on a document matching the query when the server finds it, ie an internal write lock on that document for the fraction of a millisecond that the server confirms the query is valid and applies the update

There is no system-level write lock or semaphore which a user can acquire. Full stop. MongoDB deliberately doesn't make it easy to check out a document then change it then write it back while somehow preventing others from changing that document in the meantime. (While a developer might think they want that, it's often an anti-pattern in terms of scalability and concurrency ... as a simple example imagine a client acquires the write lock then is killed while holding it. If you really want a write lock, you can make one in the documents and use atomic changes to compare-and-set it, and then determine your own recovery process to deal with abandoned locks, etc. But go with caution if you go that way.)

From what I can tell there are **two main ways the methods differ**:

- **If you want a copy of the document when your update was made: only `findAndModify` allows this**, returning either the original (default) or `new` record after the update, as mentioned; with `update` you only get a `WriteResult`, not the document, and of course reading the document immediately before or after doesn't guard you against another process also changing the record in between your read and update
- **If there are potentially multiple matching documents**: `findAndModify` only changes one, and allows you customize the `sort` to indicate which one should be changed; `update` can change all with `multi` although it defaults to just one, but does not let you say which one

Thus it makes sense what HungryCoder says, that **`update` is more efficient** where you can live with its restrictions (eg you don't need to read the document; or of course if you are changing multiple records). But for many atomic updates you *do* want the document, and `findAndModify` is necessary there.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Very clear and right to the point.

Answer (score -1):

We used findAndModify() for Counter operations (inc or dec) and other single fields mutate cases. Migrating our application from Couchbase to MongoDB, I found this API to replace the code which does GetAndlock(), modify the content locally, replace() to save and Get() again to fetch the updated document back. With mongoDB, I just used this single API which returns the updated document.