# is mongo update ($set) on a single document atomic

Tags: mongodb

I have a code similar to

```
db.myColletion.update({'_id':ObjectId("...")}, {'$set': {'state': 'CA'}})
```

Is above an atomic operation?

Do I need to use findAndModify even on single document for atomicity??

Comment: possible duplicate of [what's the diff between findAndModify and update in MongoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778493/whats-the-diff-between-findandmodify-and-update-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, all write operations with MongoDB are [atomic](https://scalegrid.io/blog/atomicity-isolation-concurrency-in-mongodb/) at the level of a single document.

The key difference between `update` and `findAnyModify` is that the latter also provides you with the original or updated document.

Answer (score 5):

See [the docs for findAndModify](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/), specifically the section on [comparisons with the update method](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/#comparisons-with-the-update-method).

> When modifying a single document, both findAndModify and the update() method atomically update the document.