# mongomapper association skips duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongomapper

I have a Document with Array of ObjectId:

```
Class Task
  key :user_id, Array
  many :userlist, class_name: 'User', :in => :user_id
```

In that Array I store different user_id values, sometimes duplicated. I can see duplicated user_id's using:

```
@task.user_id.each do |z|
  puts z
end
```

But when I fetch and associate the data using:

```
@task.userlist.each do |z|
  puts z.name
end
```

I do not get the duplicates :(, only unique id's get associated. Why?

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is exactly correct from the definition of associations
and the underlying query matching the "in" clause.
Refresh you thinking of "in" as "in the set" of *distinct* objects http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)
The fetch for userlist has an underlying query on the User collection with a $in clause,
see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

For the @task.userlist association, you will get only the documents in the User collection that match the $in clause,
the User collection is the primary "subject."
There's a significant semantic difference from

```
User.where(:user_id.in => self.user_id)
```

versus

```
self.user_id.collect |user_id| do User.where(:user_id => user_id).first; end
```

In order to get "duplicates" from the former query, you would have to have duplicate documents in the User collection,
seriously. ;-)

Hope that this helps your understanding.