# Can I use something like findAndModify on a deep nested document with MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, findandmodify

I have the Collection **contexts** with documents like the following in my MongoDB (a **context** has some **users** with **roles**)

```
{
    "__v" : 0,
    "_id" : ObjectId("53dea71a713d636e1fea705a"),
    "name" : "team4",
    "users" : [ 
        {
            "userId" : "53a347467f311d7c1731f91b",
            "roles" : [ 
                "admin"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "userId" : "536d2e8be0f9697e13b95c87",
            "roles" : []
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to add (or remove) a **role** to a **user** with [findAndModify](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can do it using both [update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) and [findAndModify](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) commands.

To add role to a user call:

```js
db.contexts.update({
  _id: ObjectId('53dea71a713d636e1fea705a'),
  'users.userId': '536d2e8be0f9697e13b95c87'
}, {
  $push: {
    'users.$.roles': 'admin'
  }
})
```

To remove role from a user call:

```
db.contexts.update({
  _id: ObjectId('53dea71a713d636e1fea705a'),
  'users.userId': '53a347467f311d7c1731f91b'
}, {
  $pull: {
    'users.$.roles': 'admin'
  }
})
```

Note that I'm using [positional operator `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) to specify an exact `user` subdocument to 
update.

Here is an example of using `findAndModify` for the same task:

```
db.contexts.findAndModify({
  query: {
    _id: ObjectId('53dea71a713d636e1fea705a'),
    'users.userId': '536d2e8be0f9697e13b95c87'
  },
  update: {
    $push: {
      'users.$.roles': 'admin'
    }
  },
  new: true
})
```

The only real difference between `update` and `findAndModify` commands is that `findAndModify` returns you a modified document, while `update` only returns operation status.

`findAndModify` operation is an equivalent of calling both `find` and `update` operations, except that `findAndModify` performs both operations in a single transaction. For more information see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10778493/1202461).