# What is the difference between $isolated and findAndModify in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, concurrency

The `$isolated` and `findAndModify` in  mongodb both prevent other processes change the document. I am confused about the different of this two method, what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

`findAndModify` does not prevent other processes change the document.

Let's say that processes A and B both try to update a document at the same time.

With `$isolated`:

1. A finds the document
2. B wants to find the document but it's prevented
3. A updates the document
4. B finds the document
5. B updates the document
6. document value is B

With `findAnyModify`:

1. A finds the document
2. B finds the document
3. B updates the document
4. A updates the document
5. document value is A

Further reading: [What's the difference between findAndModify and update in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778493/whats-the-difference-between-findandmodify-and-update-in-mongodb)